# Infinite loop triggered by absence of alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery

For reasons entirely beyond my comprehension, this function runs just fine:

```
function foo() {
    var loop = true;
    var abc = ["a","b","c"];
    var ctr = 0;
    while(loop) {
        $("<img />").error(function () {
            loop = false;
        }).attr('src','images/letters/'+abc[1]+(ctr++)+".jpg");
        alert(ctr);
    }
}
```

But moving the `alert(ctr)` outside the `while` triggers an infinite loop.

```
function foo2() {
    var loop = true;
    var abc = ["a","b","c"];
    var ctr = 0;
    while(loop) {
        $("<img />").error(function () {
            loop = false;
        }).attr('src','images/letters/'+abc[1]+(ctr++)+".jpg");
    }
    alert(ctr);
}
```

Can anyone help clarify?

Comment: i realy don't understand the sense of this function... could you please explain a little more so maybe we could find another solution?

Comment: Guys, thank you so much for the prompt response.  I should've guessed the event wasn't having a chance to fire, and it's nice to have that affirmed by the community.

@oezi - The script is checking for images that actually exist by stopping the count once the `onerror` event is fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be mighty wary of doing what you are doing. You see, you are essentially spinning off an infinite loop, relying on an `error` event thrown by JS to interrupt that loop. I imagine you are seeing the above behavior because calling `alert()` is pumping messages, and giving a chance for the event to fire. In the latter example, you are just spinning the CPU, not giving anything else a chance to happen.

Answer (score 3):

In your first snippet, the `alert` function call inside the loop causes to stop it temporarily, presumably giving time to the `error` callback to execute, setting the `loop` flag to `false`.

In your second snippet, when the `alert` call is not present within the `while`, the loop will execute many times, firing the browser's [*long-running script warning*](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/05/what-determines-that-a-script-is-long-running/).

Comment: This is right too, I just can't assign two right answers.  Thanks, CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single threaded and synchronic. If you remove the alert your loop will keep it busy and the error will not be thrown (it will be queued, actually) until the processing finishes.  The alert makes your infinite loop pause for a while and lets Javascript process the queued events.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see why, but seems like in the 2nd case there is a mixup of variable scope for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, nothing will be written to the page until either the user is explicitly given control (in your case via an alert) or the javascript reaches it natural conclusion. the .error() is never made without the alert to pause the loop.

Would it be possible to write a for loop given the length of abc?